# Запись данных в БД. Django 2.1.2

Tags: python, sql, django

Никак не могу понять, как правильно записывать данные в БД. Метод `form.save()` вызывает ошибку:

> 'PostForm' object has no attribute 'save'

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
from django.contrib import messages
from guess.models import Post, Comments
from guess.forms import PostForm, CommentsForm
# Create your views here.
class SomePosts(View):
    def get(self, request):
        get_date=Post.objects.all()
        context = {'post':get_date}
        return render_to_response('guessApp/form.html', context)

    def post(self,request):
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            db = form.save()
        else:
            print('Error')
        c = {'form':form}
        return render(request,'guessApp/form.html', c )
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from guess.models import Post, Comments
class PostForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        field = [
            'article',
             'text'
        ]


class CommentsForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields=[
            'comm'
        ]
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    article = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    text=models.TextField()
    is_created=models.DateTimeField('Date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.article

class Comments(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comm = models.TextField()
    comm_created_date = models.DateTimeField('Comments published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
```